# To Have Eclipse 4.5 in Path?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, path, eclipse

I downloaded the precompiled Eclipse Mars 4.5 in the official site [here](https://eclipse.org/downloads/).
Pseudocode

1. Extract the tarball `eclipse-jee-mars-2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`
2. Move extracted `Eclipse` directory to some location where it can be at PATH.
3. `eclipse`

### [Sjsam's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280872/16920) contribution [so deprecate this way]

1. Extract the tarball `eclipse-jee-mars-2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`
2. `sudo mv eclipse /usr/local/bin/` where `/usr/local/bin/` in my PATH
3. `sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/`
4. `eclipse`

Output

[image]

and in Terminal

> Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is
>   discouraged.

The README does not have Unix installation instructions, just Windows one.

### Additions to garethTheRed's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280875/16920)

I did

```
sudo mv eclipse /usr/local/
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/eclipse
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/local/eclipse
sudo ln -s /usr/local/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse
eclipse
```

Done!

---

How can you have Eclipse 4.5 in your Path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused because you moved `eclipse` to a location outside the directory where you installed it.

Instead of moving `eclipse` to a directory in your path, create soft link to the executable.  Assuming Eclipse is extracted within your home directory:

```
sudo ln -s /home/masi/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse
```

You can then run `eclipse` without prefixing it with the path.

Comment: I move `eclipse` directory to /usr/local/. Change permissions. Create the link. It seems other things use this workflow.

Comment: Please, see the end of the body for the completion of the case. Done!

Comment: I forgot that there is not easier approach than this. :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all moving `eclipse` binary to `/usr/local/bin/` was a bad move.

Many executables need to to link to dynamic link libraries - usually called shared objects or `.so` - to work properly.

When you moved `eclipse` to `/usr/local/bin` you might have forgotten to move its corresponding shared objects to the same location and that is why you got :

> The Eclipse executable was unable to locate its companion shared
>   library

The solution here should be simple.

1. Move Eclipse back to its original place.
2. Run `pwd` to see the absolute name of the parent directory
3. Append `export PATH=$PATH:/folder/you/got/in/the/above/step` to `/home/your_user_name/.bashrc`
4. Start a new shell session
5. Run `eclipse`

Comment: Did you install a precompiled package or did you compile eclipse from source?

Comment: Where is `eclipse` located?

Comment: You installed the .deb package to the Downloads folder? What is the file name?

Comment: You are able to launch the binary from the Downloads right?