# How can I make a program I've added to the PATH run from the terminal?

Tags: terminal, path, ln, snap, eclipse

I've followed [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280867/to-have-eclipse-4-5-in-path) to add eclipse to the path (using ln -s to make a link to /usr/local/bin/eclipse from home download), and when i type `whereis eclipse` I get /usr/local/bin/eclipse, but when I type `eclipse` into the terminal I get a snap message saying:

`Command 'eclipse' not found, but can be installed with: sudo snap install eclipse`

I explicitly went the route of downloading the tar file from Eclipse's website to avoid snap. Is this an issue with snap trying to "overide the PATH" or have I not setup eclipse into the path correctly?

Comment: Just a couple of things you could check: `echo $PATH` is `/usr/local/bin/` in the string that gets echoed? Is the file that `/usr/local/bin/eclipse` is linked to readable and executable by your user? And what happens if you run `/usr/local/bin/eclipse` in the terminal?

Comment: Which shell are you using.  Some shells might need something like `hash` may be needed to get the shell to recognize new commands added to directories in your path.

Comment: If all else fails, try logging out and back in.

Answer (score 1):

So the person who asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280867/to-have-eclipse-4-5-in-path) edited their answer to give the correct answer, but I'll do the same here in case anyone looks at this in the future.

Copied from that link:

```
sudo mv eclipse /usr/local/
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/eclipse
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/local/eclipse
sudo ln -s /usr/local/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse
eclipse
```

This makes eclipse executable and in the path, but I had issues with the icon not showing, which I was able to fix via [this link](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-eclipse-icon-not-shown-desktop-file-points-to-xpm/).

Remove the eclipse.desktop file in
`~/.local/share/applications`

That fixed the problem for me.